# is there an easier way to set PRAM?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, accessibility

I was trying to solve a stupid nagging problem (doesn't matter what at this point!) on my iMac (mid 2011), and one of the things that kept popping up is resetting PRAM. I have done this many times (over the years) and it is always a frustrating task (and getting harder as my coordination gets worse.) as I have hand/finger difficulties. One hand (the right) is cramped and mostly useless while the other is somewhat shaky. This combined with trouble with eye/hand coordination makes hitting the <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> at just the **right time** and ***all the way through*** the boot process very difficult for me. I would love to be able to set a keyboard shortcut to do that but don't think it is possible. If I could use one hand (the LEFT) to do that it would be great. I have looked in System Preferences under Keyboard and Accessibility as well as Googled but an easier solution has not revealed itself. Maybe there is none.

Comment: I did find an answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/527604/how-to-reset-mac-pram-through-the-command-line-in-lion-mountain-lion that seems to work in Yosemite. In Terminal: sudo nvram -c

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer here, [How to reset mac PRAM through the command line in Lion/Mountain Lion?](https://superuser.com/questions/527604/how-to-reset-mac-pram-through-the-command-line-in-lion-mountain-lion), that seems to work in Yosemite.

In Terminal: `sudo nvram -c`

Comment: But, you still need to reboot in order to rebuild the rvram. Be careful.

Comment: Yes, a reboot is needed.

Comment: That is beyond my limited knowledge and will require research at the least. :)